# Hazelcast get operation

Tags: java, hazelcast

Get the hazelcast value by key...

```
        IMap<tblHeaders, HazelcastJsonValue> person = hazelcastInstance.getMap("person");

        person.put(new tblHeaders("1", "ram", "0001"), new HazelcastJsonValue("{ \"name1\":\"John1\" }"));
        person.put(new tblHeaders("1", "vikas", "0002"), new HazelcastJsonValue("{ \"name2\":\"John2\" }"));
        person.put(new tblHeaders("1", "datrs", "0003"), new HazelcastJsonValue("{ \"name3\":\"John3\" }"));
```

Model Class

```
public class tblHeaders implements Serializable{  
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String school_id;
    private String name;
    private String unique_id;
```

Here How to get the value by passing single key...
example

```
HazelcastJsonValue json = person.get("school_id='0001'");
System.out.println(json.toString()); //get the value here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here.

- The IMap.get() method can only retrieve by a full key value; since you are providing only a partial key the get() method will not match anything.
- The IMap.values() method takes a Predicate argument, and is the right method to use when trying to do a query that matches based on the partial content of the key or the full or partial content of the entry's value.
- By default, a Predicate is applied against the value, but you can specify that it apply to the key by using the keyword __key (two underscores) in the attribute field of the predicate.
- Since the query may (and does) match multiple items, the correct return type is a Collection of HazelcastJsonValue.

Here's the code that will do what you're trying:

```
Predicate schoolPredicate = Predicates.equal("__key.school_id", "1");
Collection<HazelcastJsonValue> json = person.values(schoolPredicate);
System.out.println(json); //get the value here
```

Giving the output

```
[{ "name3":"John3" }, { "name1":"John1" }, { "name2":"John2" }]
```